# Tableview cell overwriting

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview

Below is my code and cells are over writing when i scroll and when i put content under if (cell==nil),nothing is shown,i don't know how to get rid of it.
when i scroll again and again it's only overwriting.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView       dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    UILabel *boothtitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 3, self.view.frame.size.width*0.5-3, 25)];
    UILabel *HouseTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 31, self.view.frame.size.width*0.5-3, 25)];
    UILabel *NameTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 59, self.view.frame.size.width*0.5-3, 25)];
    UILabel *FHNTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 87, self.view.frame.size.width*0.5-3, 25)];
    UILabel *EPICTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 115, self.view.frame.size.width*0.5-3, 25)];

    UILabel *BoothNo=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*0.5+3, 3, 200, 25)];
    UILabel *HouseNo=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*0.5+3, 31, 200, 25)];
    UILabel *Name=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*0.5+3, 59, 200, 25)];
    UILabel *EPIC=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*0.5+3, 87, 200, 25)];
    UILabel *Fnaaam=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*0.5+3, 115, 200, 25)];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:boothtitle];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:HouseTitle];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:NameTitle];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:FHNTitle];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:EPICTitle];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:BoothNo];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Name];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:HouseNo];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:EPIC];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Fnaaam];
    boothtitle.text=@"Booth Number";
    HouseTitle.text=@"House Number";
    NameTitle.text=@"Name";
    FHNTitle.text=@"F/H/M Name";
    EPICTitle.text=@"EPIC";

    BoothNo.text=[BotthID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Name.text=[nname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    HouseNo.text=[Houseno objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    EPIC.text=[EpiC objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Fnaaam.text=[FName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: @Shikha I think You should try to work with storybord . put one tableview in UIVIewController and add one TableviewCell into Tableview and add your label in cell and design it and access those label with tag in  this method - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { } if you want to work with this then i upload this method ..

Comment: @HemsMoradiya am using storyboard only

Comment: @NiravD error,undeclared identifiers. :(

Comment: table is blank now :(

Comment: Is BotthID a global variable? Have you implemented the delegate numberOfRowsInSection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, i just altered the condition. Below is the code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView       dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell != nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    UILabel *boothtitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 3, self.view.frame.size.width*0.5-3, 25)];
    UILabel *HouseTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 31, self.view.frame.size.width*0.5-3, 25)];
    UILabel *NameTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 59, self.view.frame.size.width*0.5-3, 25)];
    UILabel *FHNTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 87, self.view.frame.size.width*0.5-3, 25)];
    UILabel *EPICTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 115, self.view.frame.size.width*0.5-3, 25)];
    UIImageView *icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*0.5+90, 7, 25, 25)];

    icon.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"];

    UILabel *BoothNo=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*0.5+3, 3, 200, 25)];
    UILabel *HouseNo=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*0.5+3, 31, 200, 25)];
    UILabel *Name=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*0.5+3, 59, 200, 25)];
    UILabel *EPIC=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*0.5+3, 87, 200, 25)];
    UILabel *Fnaaam=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*0.5+3, 115, 200, 25)];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:boothtitle];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:HouseTitle];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:NameTitle];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:FHNTitle];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:EPICTitle];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:icon];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:BoothNo];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Name];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:HouseNo];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:EPIC];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Fnaaam]; 
    boothtitle.text=@"Booth Number";
    HouseTitle.text=@"House Number";
    NameTitle.text=@"Name";
    FHNTitle.text=@"F/H/M Name";
    EPICTitle.text=@"EPIC";

    BoothNo.text=[BotthID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Name.text=[nname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    HouseNo.text=[Houseno objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    EPIC.text=[EpiC objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Fnaaam.text=[FName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```